# Creating different state values for mapped objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I built a star component (used material UI component) based on the mapped object, but the star rating shows the same value when I click on any of them. How can I make each star rating have its own value based on the selection? I want each star section to show its own value.

[image: code preview]

```
import * as React from "react";
import Rating from "@mui/material/Rating";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import "./styles.css";

const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    label: "Do you like"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    label: "How do you use"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    label: "Do you dislike"
  }
];

export default function HoverRating() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(2);

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: 200, alignItems: "center" }}>
      {data.map((rate, id) => ( 
        <div>
          <p>{rate.label}</p>
          <div className="rating">
            <Rating
              value = {rate.value}
              max = {10}
              onChange = {(event, newValue) => {
                setValue(newValue);
              }}
            />
            <p>{value}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </Box>
  );
}
```

[link on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/star-rating-component-ct92m6?file=/src/App.js:0-888)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing only a single "global" rating value, store the `data` array into state and selectively update the appropriate rating object.

Example:

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    label: "Do you like",
    rating: 0
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    label: "How do you use",
    rating: 0
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    label: "Do you dislike",
    rating: 0
  }
];
```

```
export default function HoverRating() {
  const [ratings, setRatings] = React.useState(data);

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        width: 200,
        alignItems: "center"
      }}
    >
      {ratings.map((rate, index) => (
        <div>
          <p>{rate.label}</p>

          <div className="rating">
            <Rating
              value={rate.value}
              max={10}
              onChange={(event, rating) => {
                // shallow copy array and update specific index
                setRatings((ratings) => ratings.with(index, { ...rate, rating }));
              }}
            />
            <p>{rate.rating}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </Box>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit creating-different-state-value-for-mapped-object]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

create a resusable component

```
import * as React from "react";
import Rating from "@mui/material/Rating";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import "./styles.css";

const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    label: "Do you like"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    label: "How do you use"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    label: "Do you dislike"
  }
];

export default function HoverRating() {


  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        width: 200,
        alignItems: "center"
      }}
    >
      {data.map((rate, id) => (
        <RatingComponent rate={rate}/>
       
      ))}
    </Box>
  );
}

function RatingComponent ({rate}) {

  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(2);

  return (
    <div>
    <p>{rate.label}</p>
    <div className="rating">
      {" "}
      <Rating
        value={rate.value}
        max={10}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
      />
      <p>{value} </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).